# How do you delete a Web SQL database in Android's default browser?

Tags: android, mobile, web-sql, offlineapps

This is a web sql browser. I guess they recently switched to chrome so in newer versions it might be an idb thing but this problem is with web sql.

Settings > Privacy and security > Clear cache (Clear locally cached content and databases) does not work. I know this because after running the same test 10 times I finally changed the name of the database from abc to def and it worked. I also know this because there is old data I can access even after clearing the cache.

Answer (score 0):

nm, apparently you can do it in settings on the device level. it wiped all of my bookmarks too though. anyone know a way to just get rid of the db?